# how to read response header values in feature file of karate framework?

Tags: cucumber, karate

example: 
I am getting response as 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK,OK OK,OK OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
eventid: 24FCE4D8FA4E6E1212E71960612312321
uuid: ec00d8f0-b168-489e-996e-234234234wer

how to retreive the response header value of field eventid? it tried as " def event = response.eventid "in feature file  but getting "pathnotfoundexception"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the documentation: [`responseHeaders`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#responseheaders).

```
* def eventId = responseHeaders['eventid'][0]
```